# Applying style files to vectors and rasters in PyQGIS 3.22

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am seeing different behaviours when applying style files to rasters and vectors.  This code opens a vector, fixes the geometry and adds that to the map with a preset style from a qml file:

```
#add, fix and style the  vector
segname=outname[:-4]+'.gpkg'
#result = iface.addVectorLayer(segname, "", "ogr")
segname2=outname[:-4]+'_fix.gpkg'
#layer = iface.activeLayer()
fix_layer = processing.run("native:fixgeometries", {'INPUT':segname,'OUTPUT':segname2})['OUTPUT']
result = iface.addVectorLayer(segname2, "", "ogr")
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.loadNamedStyle('/media/patrice/DataDrive/GORiM/ManualFineTuning/SegmentStyle.qml')
layer.triggerRepaint()
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
```

This code adds the raster, but does nothing with the style file.

```
Zone=os.path.basename(images[i])[-8:-4]
Sample=os.path.basename(images[i])[3:7]
#add the image
Cname=os.path.basename(images[i])[:-4]
#print(uri)
rlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(images[i],Cname,"gdal")
vLayer = iface.activeLayer()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
extent = vLayer.extent()
iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(extent)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.loadNamedStyle('/media/patrice/DataDrive/GORiM/ManualFineTuning/ImageNIRStyle.qml')
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Any ideas why? Both style files work fine when used manually in QGIS symbology.

Answer (score 1):

It was a typo in my style file name.  Useful info is that the console did NOT return an error for a non-existent file.